# compress and email option in right click

Tags: email, nemo

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 with the Nemo file manager.

How can I enable a right click option which compresses files into a zip archive and attaches it to a new E-Mail in Thunderbird?

Comment: You want a file to be compressed and attached to a new E-Mail?

Comment: Which file manager do you use? Ubuntu's default **Nautilus**, or **Nemo**, which is often used with Cinnamon, as it is default in Mint. Or something else? Right click actions are handled by the file manager, not by the desktop environment.

Comment: Oh sorry.. it is nemo

Comment: Compress in what way? tar? zip?

Comment: Compress in zip

Answer (score 2):

Create a script(.nemo_action) to do that, [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action) you can find a sample for correct syntax.

When you finish your script add it to `nemo-actions` to make it available to right click. You have to add it to 
`$HOME/.local/share/nemo/actions/`

The script has to have `.nemo_action` extension

Now you have to make script for compressing and mail:

Add the need to the script:

To compress using zip for example:

```
zip -r attach.zip attachFiles
```

Now attach it to  a new mail in thunderbird:

```
thunderbird -compose "attachment='/path-to- attach.zip'"
```

So this script will be called by the `nemo_action` one

Some useful links:

- [Arch Nemo Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo)
- [Behind the curtain.. Nemo actions](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2013/05/behind-the-curtain-nemo-actions/)
- [How to make nemo support compressing files by context menu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82768/how-to-make-nemo-support-compressing-files-by-context-menu)

Comment: You cannot put a whole sequence of commands into a nemo_action file, such as you can't in desktop files. You can start a shell progress, but I think that makes it somewhat ugly...

Comment: @the_Seppi I agree with you and this what i meant above, ill elaborate more

Answer (score 1):

You need two scripts for that: The Nemo action script and the script that will actually do the work: (Well, actually one would be enough, but it would make maintenance veeery annoying)

The action script for the right click will have to go into a very specific directory:

```
~/.local/share/nemo/actions/compress-and-mail.nemo_action:
```

As it doesn't expand `~` or `$HOME`, you'll have to give a full path.

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Compress and E-Mail
Comment=zip-compress files and send them with Thunderbird
Icon-Name=thunderbird
Exec=/home/saravanabawa/.local/nemo_mail_compress.sh %F
Selection=notnone
Extensions=any
EscapeSpaces=true
```

The other script will be a bash script to compress the selected files, attach the temporary archive to a new message and delete it as soon as Thunderbird closes. The file will have to be at the location you specified in the `Exec=` line in the previous script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ATT=$(mktemp /tmp/attachment.XXXXX.zip)             #Generate temp file
rm $ATT                                             #Remove temp file
zip -rj $ATT $@                                     #Compress files
thunderbird -compose "attachment='file://${ATT}'"   #Attach zip to message
rm $ATT                                             #Delete archive when done
```

Yes, I'm first creating a temp file and then delete it again. This way a file name is generated, but `zip` doesn't complain about the file not being a zip archive.

The script I created allows you to attach multiple files and directories. Due to some limitations, it is either possible to compress the whole path (the archive will take the whole path as name, eventually containing the directory tree from `/` to all of the compressed files) or to omit all directories, i.e. all files will be at root level. Duplicate file names in  different directories will cause the program not to work properly (I never use zip, I don't know how it will react). If you wish the first behavior, remove the `j` switch from the zip command, else leave it there.

---

PS: Recipients may be suspicious if they receive an E-Mail with an attachment called `attachment.JgHdI.zip` (name generated by mktemp). So you may want to rename the archive inside Thunderbird.

Another option would be to query for an archive name, e.g. using Zenity. An adapted script could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ATT="/tmp/$(zenity ---entry --title='Enter file name' --text='Please name the attachment archive').zip"
zip -rj $ATT $@
thunderbird -compose "attachment='file://${ATT}'"
rm $ATT
```

Comment: I got compress and email option in Right click. but it is not working @the_Seppi

Comment: Did you `chmod +x` the bash script?

Comment: Yes, it asking attachment file name, after enter it opens thunderbird composer but no attachment is there.

Comment: Can you modify the script so it will output the value of ATT to a file, so as to see whether the name is correctly accepted? (something like `echo $ATT >> /home/saravanabawa/tbcdebug`). Also comment out the last line (prepend a hash sign: `#rm $ATT`) and then have a look at the actual archive stored at `/tmp/<name>.zip`.

Answer (score 1):

For Thunderbird in Ubuntu 16.10 for Nemo 3.20 I adapted this solution: http://www.badpenguin.org/nemo-action-send-to-email

- go to `/usr/share/nemo/actions`
- open as root (in Nemo)
- copy sample script
- rename to: `thunderbird.nemo_action`
- open it and insert following content:

  ```
  [Nemo Action]
  Name=Attach to Email
  Comment=Attach to Email
  Exec=thunderbird -compose to=,"attachment='%U'"
  Icon-Name=thunderbird
  Selection=notnone
  Extensions=nodirs;
  Separator=,
  EscapeSpaces=false
  ```
- close nemo: `nemo -q`
- on right clicking a file in Nemo you will now find "Attach to Email" in the menu!